# How to intizialize and push objcet in array, into constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

There is in application "target" drop-down, witn two elements in that drop-down. 
I created Model (NameValueModel) with two parametars and construcor:

```
1. name:string
2. value:string
3. constructor(name, value) { this.name=name; this.value=value; }
```

In main class I want to create:

```
1. list of this objects
2. initialize the list in constructor
3. After that push two new NameValueModel-s in that list. (This step is problem for me)

I need to push this objects: 
a) name: "New window", value: "_blank"
b) name: "Current window", value: "_self"
```

What I do so far is:

```
1. Create Model with 2 parmas and constrcutor

2. In main class create 
a) List of objects: selectedTargets: NameValueModel[]; 
b) Trying to push objects into lsit:
 constructor() {
   this.selectedTargets.push(new NameValueModel("Current window", "_self")); 
   this.selectedTargets.push(new NameValueModel("New window", "_blank"));
 }
```

On the end I need to provide:  let target = this.selectedTargets.**value**;

But compailer does not give me to put Value, only "Values"  this.selectedTargets.**values**;

How I can fix this? Or this way of implemetation is ok?

Comment: this.selectedTargets[0].name or this.selectedTargets[0].value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand you very well, but I guess this is what you need,
you need to initiate the array first

```
 selectedTargets:NameValueModel[]=[]; 
    constructor() {
      this.selectedTargets.push({name:"Current window", value:"_self"}); 
      this.selectedTargets.push({name:"New window", value:"_blank"});
    }
```

Comment: and you could declare your NameValueModel as Interface like that                  `export interface NameValueModel{
    name:string;
    value:string;
}`

Comment: Yes thank you. Both answers are exactly what I need.